# Is it possible to make an "easy" high power amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, audio

For example, an LM317 can handle currents up to 1.5 amps, but if you add a few 2N3055 power transistors you can get pretty much unlimited power (if you have good enough cooling and components that can handle those amps)

There are many circuits out there on how to build an amplifier, but most of them are too advanced for me, I'm looking for a way to build a minimum of 500w amplifier using some amplifier IC, let's take an LM386 for example, is it possible to just add power transistors to make a small LM386 amp to a high power amp?

Thanks!

Comment: *"I don't know much about cars, but please give me plans to build a high performance sports car with a adjustable wrench, a pair of plyers, and two screw drivers."*  500 W is advanced.  There is nothing we can say that makes any sense short of supplying every detail.  There is no such thing as a *500 W amp for dummies*.

Comment: I already voted to close as too broad.  Now I'm also downvoting on account of your attitude.  Whether you like it or not, what I said above is true.

Comment: I see, I have built a 1.25 - 30 volt power supply that can supply up to 30 amps using the LM317. So i thought there might be some similar way with an amplifier (even tho a power supply is different)

Comment: Now you're deleting comments I have replied to.  *Screw this*.

Comment: What? I deleted my own comment because i thought it was inappropriate BEFORE you answered. But whatever

Comment: I saw it and answered it, with a comment and a downvote.

Comment: What kind of signal do you want to amplify?

Comment: What do you mean with signal? I want to drive a powerful subwoofer. Thanks!

Comment: You could buy a class D amp chip and follow the reference design (in the datasheet for the chip in question), but you'd appear to be far better off (based on info so far) to simply buy a class D amp and call it a day.

Comment: Thank you, Yeah. I think I'm just gonna get some money and buy a high quality used one, In the meantime I'll read more about it and maybe try to build one in a year or so :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the devil is in the detail. In principle the answer to your question is yes. I am presuming that you mean an audio amplifier. At that power level you will be wanting a push-puill output stage. Unlike a simple regulator, that has to cope with current in both directions. When the current direction changes with a push pull stage, one power transistor takes over from the other. If that is not dome smoothly you get cross-over distortion. The quiescent current power stage has to be controlled. Changes in VBE (or VGS) in the power transistor due to temperature and load variation have to be catered for. It is these things which lead to the complexity that you see in regular designs. If you don't want to deal with the issues, the best bet is to use off the shelf amplifier blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Yep i think I'll just buy an amplifier instead.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want an IC driver that takes care of most of the issues that user1582568 mentioned. Something like [LME49811](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lme49811.pdf) or [LME49830](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snaa058b/snaa058b.pdf) comes with good documentation and enables 500W/1kW designs with parallel output transistors. Note that unlike usual audio power/op-amps these LME ICs have input/outputs for the
thermal compensation transistors (that need to be placed on the same heatsink
as the actual power stage transistors.)

You can find 3rd-party ready made boards for these, e.g. [here](http://www.pansonaudio.com/initial_lme49810.htm) they make two-board solutions, just to give you an idea what the finished product could look like.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip! You too user1582568. I will check that out! :)